# Get Text from UILabel when it's Tapped using TextKit

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, core-text, textkit

I want to get the word when the UILabel is Tapped. I've tried using it with the TextKit. This is What I did:

Assigned my label (attLabel) an attributed string: "**Rachel** has requested to join the **Group**". Also, I've added a tap gesture on the label.
nameRange is the range of **Rachel**.
Now, in the gesture action:

```
    @IBAction func didTapLabel(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attLabel.attributedText!)

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: attLabel.frame.size)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

    let touchPoint = sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView: attLabel)        

    var glyphRange:NSRange = NSRange()
    layoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange(nameRange!, actualGlyphRange: &glyphRange)

    let glyphRect = layoutManager.boundingRectForGlyphRange(glyphRange, inTextContainer: textContainer)

    if CGRectContainsPoint(glyphRect, touchPoint) {
        NSLog("Contains name")
    }
}
```

But now the issue is, when I tap on the "h" of Rachel, it doesn't prints out the name. But If I click on "R", "a" or "c" it prints out the name. 
So what should I do to get the correct word? Similarly I want the action to happen when **Group** is tapped. Also, I want a little highlighting of the word, when that word is pressed.